# spinner in kotlin not populating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, spinner

my spinner is not populating

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   
    
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(requireContext(), R.array.duration, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) as SpinnerAdapter
    _binding?.duration?.adapter = adapter
    _binding?.duration?.onItemSelectedListener = object :
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>,
                                    view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            val followeredata = followerData()
            var followercount = followeredata.getcount(position)
                Log.i("menu selected"," on item is selected")
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    }


    }
```

I have tried different methods of creating adapter but none of them are able to populate the spinner. but if I create them from XML:entries it works fine. how do I populate my spinner from code

Comment: You said creating it from XML entries works fine, but your code is creating from an array in XML? So what exactly is your issue with this code?

Comment: the issue arises in XML when I implement in click listener it doesn't work, so I tried doing it with code. but code is worst. code doesn't even populate the spinner.

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation? In particular for the `createFromResource` method?